# Phonegap native tab bar in ipad app

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ipad, cordova

I am  using [Phonegap.0.9.6](http://www.phonegap.com/), trying to get native tab bar in iPad app but no luck

I download `NativeControls` from github and setup

By adding `.m` and `.h` file in plugin directory and .js file in `www` directory also adding that `.js` file in `index.html`. also added`NativeControls` as a key and value in `phonegap.plist` file and using below code in index.html but no luck.

```javascript
var nativeControls;
var tabBarItems = new Array('More','Favorites','Search');

function onBodyLoad()
{
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
}

/* When this function is called, PhoneGap has been initialized and is ready to roll */
function onDeviceReady()
{             
    nativeControls = window.plugins.NativeControls;            
    setupTabBar();   
    showTabBar();
}

function setupTabBar()
{           
    nativeControls.createTabBar();                       
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tabBarItems.length; i++)
    {
        setUpButton(tabBarItems[i]);
    }
    nativeControls.showTabBarItems('More', 'Search', 'Favorites');   
}

function showTabBar()
{
    var options = new Object();
    options.position = 'bottom';
    nativeControls.showTabBar(options);
}

function hideTabBar()
{
    nativeControls.hideTabBar();
}

function setUpButton(name)
{
    var options = new Object();
    options.onSelect = function()
    {
        alert(name);
    };
    nativeControls.createTabBarItem(name, name, 'tabButton:'+name, options);
}        

function onFail(mesage) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

thanks.

Comment: function onDeviceReady()
{             
    nativeControls = window.plugins.nativeControls;            
    setupTabBar(); 
    
}

Comment: thanks shazron to fix the problem nativeControls = window.plugins.nativeControls;

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still look for a solution, like I was, I found https://github.com/tblomseth/cordova-ios-tab-bar which was based on `Native Controls`. I made a few tweaks and a working example here: https://github.com/squerb/cordova-ios-tab-bar.

Answer (score 0):

According to their wiki:

> UIControls are now officially dead as of 0.9.2 and will not be
>   supported (it never really was officially part of the core). If you
>   still want this functionality have a look
>   at:http://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/NativeControls/

[Source](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494801/iPhone%3a%20UIControls%20%28TabBar%29)